# Property '_touched' is private and only accessible within class 'AbstractControl'.?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

**Production Build Error**

Hi i am using ReactiveForms in Angular Project , When I try to ng build --prod i got the following error

> ```
> ng-details/billing-details.component.html (40,6): Property '_touched' is private
>  and only accessible within class 'AbstractControl'.
> ```

Below is my code I dont know what Went Wrong?

```
  paymentForm = new FormGroup({
    companyName: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
    companyAddress: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
    gstNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
    country: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
    cardNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[0-9]{12}')),
    cardName: new FormControl('')    
  });
```

Html

```
<div class="common-error" *ngIf="paymentForm.controls.country._touched && !paymentForm.controls.country.valid"> Please enter Company Name. (Min 3 char)</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you refer to the `_touched` property, instead of the `touched` property?

`_touched` is an internal implementation detail of Angular. Please only use the public variables.

Try:

```
paymentForm.controls.country.touched
```

Answer (score 1):

You can User Touched property in formControl as mentioned in bellow example. `FormControlName` Property is there to define name of your input control.

```
<input id="name" class="form-control"
      formControlName="name" required >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">
</div>
```